# How does the Embedded Neo4j actually work?

Tags: java, neo4j

I am new to neo4j and based on the reading I have done so far it seem there are two ways to interact with neo4j using Neo4j REST and Embedded. Where I am a little confused is does the Embedded option only give you the ability use the native Neo4j API to manipulate the datastore or can you also embed Neo4j and package it with your java application and if so how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, Embedded term coined out to integrate neo4j with your application. In embedded mode, your db is locked and your application is solely authorized to access it. You can not access your db from any where else as far as your application is running and accessing it.

Where as in Neo4j Rest or Say **Neo4j Server** support REST API through which you can perform all the data store related operation via API call. In Rest API mode, you can handle your db externally using Neo4j GUI console along with your application.

Performance wise, I found embedded mode is much faster than Server mode.

> does the Embedded option only give you the ability use the native Neo4j API to manipulate the datastore

You can use either of mode (Server REST API mode or embedded mode) to manipulate datastore.

> Package with Java Application

it depends on your application configuration, in embedded mode you generally don't need external neo4j server running. You just need to explicitly mention your db path along with other configuration (I have used Spring data neo4j). Where as in Neo4j Server mode, you will require neo4j server running.

You can have look on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224523/neo4j-server-vs-embedded) as well.

Comment: You can also write server extensions which also use the embedded APIs.  Usually nowadays we recommend to use Cypher across the transactional http endpoint, not the REST API.

Comment: Ok, so since the DB is locked when using the embedded option how would that affect an application that relies an some Cloud infrastructure like Heroku or Google App Engine.

Comment: @MarioDennis if your concern is toward embedded neo4j db on cloud infrastructure, then it should not affect your application, as your app itself going to create embedded db on given mentioned path of local system. usually path is given as **/home/build/neo4j/db/graph.db** where graph.db will be created by your app using neo4j library. If I understood you properly.

Comment: I am not sure about Heroku and Google App Engine, but if your deploying app to Amazon instance, then above comment make sense :).