# Neo4j Server vs Embedded mode

Tags: neo4j

I wanted to know exactly what is meant by neo4j server and the embedded mode. Even i gone through the post [Neo4j Server vs. Embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224523/neo4j-server-vs-embedded). But i dint get clearly those concepts. I have installed neo4j 2.1.1 on windows 64bit machine which is a neo4j server. So when neo4j embedded mode will come into picture?

Also how can we switch between embedded mode to server mode or vice-versa?

When i was working with mysql to neo4j migration(using batch-import), after importing the nodes and relationships into neo4j getting a message in a `messages.log` file as below:

```
Clean shutdown on BatchInserter(EmbeddedBatchInserter[C:\Users\Neo4j\t2.db])
```

How embedded is appearing here if i have installed neo4j server ? So please clarify these queries.

Thanks

Comment: The docs are a little vague about this, but embedded simply means what the name suggests: an embedded server is part of your app, not something separate that your app connects to.

Comment: Ya even came to know that neo4j embedded database created from our application using neo4j libraries in the specified path. But to view the embedded database in a neo4j sever , how can i see it? How can i switch between embedded to server mode??

Comment: I'm pretty new to Neo4j myself, but I think you could copy the files from the embedded instance and run a server with the copy.  And clustering is built into Neo4j, so you could run a cluster with both embedded and server nodes.

Comment: ya i did the same thing, copied the embedded database into neo4j server ans started the server where i'm getting an error of Embedded batch importer.

Answer (score 9):

Embedded databases run inside of your application, meaning they're in the same JVM as your application.  In general, with embedded databases you'll do direct database access or cypher queries.   There are a lot of pros and cons here - one of the cons is that your JVM process locks the database; you can't have a bunch of different applications in different JVMs accessing the same embedded database at the same time.   The pro is direct access.

When you're running a server, usually that means you're using the web admin components which also provide a set of RESTful services.  The pro of this is that it's in a different JVM.  Meaning you could access it more easily from other programming languages, over the network, and so on.  You could have many applications in many JVMs all talking to a server instance via RESTful services.  Generally access isn't as fast, but it's more flexible.  When you run it this way though, direct access to the graph inside of a java application (using the Neo4J API) is off limits.

If you want to run the web admin/GUI stuff and RESTful services from within an embedded database, you can do that.  [See these instructions for how.](http://fooo.fr/~vjeux/github/github-recommandation/db/doc/manual/html/server-embedded.html#_starting_the_server_from_java)

Here's a code snippet: what you need is the `WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper`.

```
AbstractGraphDatabase graphdb = getGraphDb();
WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper srv;
srv = new WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper( graphdb );
srv.start();
// The server is now running
// until we stop it:
srv.stop();
```

Comment: @ Frobber thanks for the useful information. Above you have given code snippet to run the web amin/gui from within an embedded database but  I ahve not wiritten any java code . So where should i need to fit the above codes snippet. I used batch importer to import data from mysql to neo4j. After importing i'm not able to start the ne04j server for the newly created database using the batch-import command. So what i need to do ?

Comment: I'm getting the error as below:`o.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase - Startup failed: Component org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@525c6957' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@49643715' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.: 'neostore.nodestore.db' has a store version number that we cannot upgrade from. Expected 'NodeStore v0.A.1' but file is version 'NodeStore v0.A.0'.`. I'm generating db using batch-import.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits does embedded = in-memory here?

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk yes

Comment: @FrobberOfBits isn't the data going to be persisted on the disk whether neo4j running on embedded mode or rest mode? How can you say it's in-memory?