# embedded Neo4j in JVM

Tags: java, neo4j

I am trying to access a neo4j database from my java program. I tried to create a fresh db and query it, and it ran successfully as per: http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorials-java-embedded

Code:

```
String DB_PATH = "C:/Users/singsand/Documents/Neo4j/newdb";
    File f=new File(DB_PATH);
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb =   new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(f);
    try (Transaction tx=graphDb.beginTx()){
        graphDb.execute("CREATE (table1:car {name:'car1'})");
        tx.success();
    }
```

But then I started this db as a server through the Neo4j community edition tool and also accessed it through my browser.

After that, when i executed the same java program I used above, it throws the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory, C:\Users\singsand\Documents\Neo4j\newdb
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:144)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:40)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:100)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.lambda$createDatabaseCreator$193(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:89)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:183)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:65)
    at neo4j.neo4jdemo.App.main(App.java:41)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.Recovery@62fca613' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:416)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:98)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:508)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:99)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:140)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized log entry version -9. At position LogPosition{logVersion=0, byteOffset=16} and entry version null
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.entry.LogEntryVersion.byVersion(LogEntryVersion.java:147)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.entry.VersionAwareLogEntryReader.readLogEntry(VersionAwareLogEntryReader.java:83)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.LogEntryCursor.next(LogEntryCursor.java:50)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.LatestCheckPointFinder.find(LatestCheckPointFinder.java:77)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.PositionToRecoverFrom.apply(PositionToRecoverFrom.java:53)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.DefaultRecoverySPI.getPositionToRecoverFrom(DefaultRecoverySPI.java:112)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.Recovery.init(Recovery.java:72)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:406)
    ... 16 more
```

I have seen similar errors in other Stack Overflow questions, but wasn't able to solve my issue using their solutions.

Comment: Did you delete this question and re-post it?  I remember asking for clarification that you're trying to run standalone and embedded servers *at the same time* using the same database files.

Comment: No, I'm not trying to run the standalone and embedded version at the same time. So what I did was: run it as embedded and put a few nodes in the db. Then start it as a server through the Neo4j tool, and view it in my browser. Then i stopped the server from the tool. Then i tried to use it again as embedded, through my program. That's when i get this error.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly. You are using embedded version of Neo4j in your app and than you are trying to start Neo4j server on your localhost. Is that right?

[Neo4j Server vs Embedded mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24933568/69684)

The thing is Neo4j embedded is running as part of your Java application. Neo4j server is standalone service which is run separately. And you can't combine those two on the same db.

If you want to use Neo4j browser with your embedded db this should help you - http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/11/21/neo4j-browser-with-embedded.html

Comment: So, I was using an embedded version of Neo4j in my program. After that program exited, I started the same DB as a server through the Neo4j community edition tool and accessed it from the browser. Now when I run the same program with the db embedded, it throws an error.

So as I can understand from what you said, I can't use it as a service through the Neo4j tool, even though at that time the program isn't running?